# The best overloaded method match for Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.GridEditingSettingsBuilder

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

The best overloaded method match for `Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.GridEditingSettingsBuilder` `Mode(Kendo.Mvc.UI.GridEditMode)`  has some invalid arguments   .Filterable() and  .Scrollable()

This is the error I get while I run the project which has the KendoUI Grid Control.

The code is similar to what is there in the KendoUI website , however on my project I do get this error.  I am able to get the Filterable() option in the intellisense but am not sure why the error is thrown . I can see the error in Firebug and it is not thrown by the webpage as a yellow screen of death.

Any help would be appreciated. 
My sample code is as below

### CS HTML Code

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication29.Models.CustomItem>



<div class="absolute-position">
  <div class="absolute-position">

      @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {


            columns.Bound(o => o.No).Width("15%");
            columns.Bound(o => o.ShortDesc).Width("15%");
            columns.Bound(o => o.Category).Width("6%");




        })               
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable(p=>p.Refresh(true))
               .Filterable()
               .Scrollable()
               .Editable(edit => edit.DisplayDeleteConfirmation("Are You Sure To Delete This ").Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
        .ColumnMenu(col=>col.Sortable(false))
        .Groupable()
        .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
        .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
        .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
        //.ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()

            .PageSize(6)
                     .Read(read => read.Action("GetItemsHome", "det"))  
            .Model(model => {
                model.Id(p => p.ID);


                })

                    .Create(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Create", "det"))
                      //  .Read(read => read.Action("EditingInline_Read", "Default1"))
                        .Update(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Update", "det"))
                        .Destroy(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Destroy", "det"))

    )



)



  </div>
</div>
```

///CS Code

```
 public ActionResult GetItemsHome1([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request , int page)
    {
        List<CustomItem> lst = new List<CustomItem>();

        return Json(lst.ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }
```